# I could create the root index.html page but could not create another page in Django

Tags: python, django

I have made a simple Django design in which I displayed a database for Medical blood test items. I successfully made the typical three files (views, the app URLS, and the basic URLS) as follows:

**Views.py**

```
from .models import Test
from django.shortcuts import render
def index(request):
    tests = Test.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'btestinfo/index.html',  {'tests': tests})

def contact(request):
    return render(request, 'btestinfo/contact.html')
```

**App URLS**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    # path('<int:test_id>', views.detail, name='tests_detail'),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact')
]
```

**Basic URLS**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("btestinfo/", include("btestinfo.urls")),
    path("contact/", include("contact.urls"))
]
```

I exhausted all my tricks to create a link like http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact in order to display the contact.html page, am always ending up with the error:

***ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'contact'***

I was only able to display the the db items from the link http://127.0.0.1:8000/btestinfo.

I will be so grateful if you get to my rescue

Comment: This: `path("contact/", include("contact.urls"))` **includes** this path: `path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact')` so you would end up with using `http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/contact`.  So change your **APP URLS** to `path('', views.contact, name='contact')` might work.

Comment: @raphael thanks for your input, but if I use your app urls there will be no specific link for the contact page, there will only be a reference to it

Comment: I don't believe you are correct.  Perhaps I'm not understanding.  Check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76695873/10951070)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if `App URLS` is `btestinfo.urls` file. But let's assume it does.
What you actually do right now is attaching your two URL's from `App URLS` to `btestinfo/`:

```
btestinfo/          > views.index
btestinfo/contact/  > views.contact
```

I guess that you will see the contact page if you access `http://127.0.0.1:8000/btestinfo/contact/`.
The error message also says that the file `contact.urls` cannot be found.

I think you want to implement the following:

Basis URL file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("btestinfo.urls")),
]
```

App URL file:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("btestinfo/", views.index, name="index"),
    path("contact/", views.contact, name="contact")
]
```

This will make the following URLs available:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/btestinfo/
http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/
```

Read more about URLs in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/urls/) to understand how this will all work.

Comment: You were right, thank you so much, but also I had to add the
``` path("btestinfo/", include("btestinfo.urls"))```
in order to get the main desired outcome result

Comment: But what confuses me,  if we have included the statement 
`path("", include("btestinfo.urls")),`
why the link 
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/btestinfo/` did not work only after I added the statement 
`path("btestinfo/", include("btestinfo.urls"))`

Comment: Django uses the first match in the url ptterns it finds. Make sure you don't have duplicates.

Comment: Problem solved with the help of @Marco and another contributor

Answer (score 0):

When the url matches `contact/` in your project-wide, **root urls.py**, Django sees that for that pattern it needs to search your **contact** apps **urls.py**.

```py
# project-wide urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("btestinfo/", include("btestinfo.urls")),
    path("contact/", include("contact.urls"))    # ALL urls here will start with http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/
]
```

It now has http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/ *already* and will ADD the path found in the app specific urls.py.

```py
# contact app urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.contact, name='contact')    # ADD '' to the root url
]
```

But, what is added is `''` so the url remains http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/.

If, for example you have other urls related to the contact app you would add them:

```py
# contact app urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.contact, name='contact')    # ADD '' to the root url for contact
    path('another-page-of-the-contact-app', views........)    # ADD another-page-of-the-contact-app to the end of the root url
    path('YET-another-page-of-the-contact-app', views........)
]
```

Then, in order to go to `another_page_of_the_contact_app` your url in the browswer would be http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/another-page-of-the-contact-app.

And if you wanted to later go to `YET_another_page_of_the_contact_app` you would have the link http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/YET-another-page-of-the-contact_app.